# CSS Responsive Images Elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hi I'm trying to create a Responsive Email Template.

I can't make the background images responsive.

Here is a sample of the images code:

```css
a#logo {
    display: block;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 171px;
    height: 119px;
    background: url('http://tophitechgadgets.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/logo3.png')no-repeat;
    margin: 14px auto;
}
```

Also I want to ask some ideas to make it look perfect responsive site.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nLxjU/2/

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what your expectations of 'responsive' are? I'd recommend you read http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/08/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/ as it stands, the question is too broad

Comment: I mean the background images. I have several background images on my jsfiddle code and want to know how to make them responsive. If there's a way you can check the code there and see what went wrong why the images are not responsive fluid. that includes my a#logo, .divider, a#learn-more etc

Comment: if this what you mean: http://jsfiddle.net/nLxjU/3/ ?

Comment: Still the images (including the logo, learn more, banner) are not responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you're using a background image, make sure the element's `width` is `100%` and not `600px` and use `background-position: center center` to position the the image properly. I was able to fix most of your images this way.

http://jsfiddle.net/myajouri/nLxjU/5/

Comment: found some error with the background-position: center center; however I have one last question                                                                  for "a.btn" (LEARN MORE BUTTON ON THE LOWER PART UNDER Check our site for coupons) why is not moving even though I'm adding a margin-top?? would you mind checking??

Comment: it's not moving because the margins are collapsing. Adding `display: inline-block` to it should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

look at this: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3107/css3-support-in-email-clients/

You will see what you are trying to achieve is hard if not impossible. Background-size is css3 which is not widely supported by email clients. You probably need to do it differently.

Comment: Is there a way you can check the code on JS fiddle? to make the images responsive? so that I can check what went wrong? DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nLxjU/2/

Comment: how do you normally test responsive sites? it's the same principle with and email - use a web browser

Answer (score 0):

Alot of email clients doesn't support css3 so you wont be able to use Background-size, Why not add an image in instead? if you needed a element on top of it position it absolute.

Comment: Yeah but my problem is the images getting responsive. Is there a way you can check the code on JS fiddle? to make the images responsive? so that I can check what went wrong? DEMO: jsfiddle.net/nLxjU/2

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of all elements you currently have background/background-image properties set for, and instead replace the respective elements with `<img>` elements, the width of which needs to be set to `100%` and placed within a containing element with a defined width that the images can use for a reference - being a responsive template I'm guessing this container should have a `%` width.

That said, you still havent clarified what your expectations of 'responsiveness' are, the above will work for simple width % resizing, if you want stacking or overflowing on resize, this is different and will require more work, which may or may not be supported in recipients email clients. I would say again, have a look a [this article](http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/08/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/). As ever when it comes to HTML email, my advice would be to keep it simple and stick with what works. E.g. a fixed template inclusive of images as small as you can make them (kb wise) with as simple a DOM as possible- this will prevent that awful scenario of a design looking great to you, but terrible to everyone who receives it.

nb. Given the amount of code provided in the fiddle, you may want to break down your question, as its less likely someone will refactor the whole template for you I'm afraid.